# Convergence of series related to prime gaps and Gilbreath's conjecture

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, constants, prime-gaps

Gilbreath's conjecture states that when we take the absolute values of the consecutive differences of prime numbers, as so :

$$
2, 3, 5, 7,11,13,17,19,23,...  \\
1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4,...  \\
1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,...  \\
1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0,...  \\
1, 2, 0, 0, 0,...  \\
1, 2, 0, 0,...  \\
(...), 
$$

we will get only 1s in the first column (if we ignore the first term that is a $2$).

My interest lies in the second column, where the $3$ at the beginning is ignored. The conjecture implies that should always be either a $0$ or a $2$. The sequence created by those numbers (A089582 in the OEIS) is the following :

$$
2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, ...
$$

We see that if we subtract $1$ from each term, we get a supposedly infinite sequence of $1$s and $-1$s at approximately equal proportions :
$$
1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, ...
$$
Let $\Delta_\pi(n)$ denote the $n$th term of that sequence (because we can),
do the following sums converge? If so, for what values of $s$ and what is their respective values?

$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \frac{\Delta_\pi(n)}{n^s}$$
$$\sum_{p\mathrm{\ is\ prime}} \frac{\Delta_\pi(p)}{p^s}$$
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \frac{\Delta_\pi(n)}{(p(n))^s}$$
NB: $p(n)$ denotes the $n$ prime number

Comment: see my comment here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3056991/bounds-on-primes-with-gilbreaths-conjecture#comment6303021_3056991). Since Gilbreath works for almost anything and not just primes, i am not sure you can get anything of it.